# javascript - how do i flatten an array of json into an array of a particular json attributes?

Tags: javascript

So lets say i have an array like so

```
[ 
    {name: "a", happyName: "bob" }
    , {name: "b", happyName: "cow" }
    , {name: "c", happyName: "moo" }
    , {name: "d", happyName: "jen" }
]
```

What is the most efficient manner to flatten it to an array like so:

```
[ "a","b","c","d"]
```

(or alternatively to get only the happyName in the values instead - to be precise, i suppose, how would i flatten some given array into an array of some given named json attribute?)

**NB** this is javascript only, no JQuery etc stuff please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good use case for [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var names = theArray.map(function(item) {
    return item.name;
});

var happyNames = theArray.map(function(item) {
    return item.happyName;
});
```

If you have to do this a lot, it's quite easy to create a helper:

```
var names = values(theArray, 'name'),
    happyNames = values(theArray, 'happyName');

function values(arr, attr) {
    return arr.map(function(item) {
        return item[attr];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for that

```
var names = arr.map(function(obj) {
    return obj.name;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Dr8YL/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [ 
 {name: "a", happyName: "bob" }
 , {name: "b", happyName: "cow" }
 , {name: "c", happyName: "moo" }
 , {name: "d", happyName: "jen" }
]

var names = arr.map(function(e) { return e.name } )
```

Answer (score 1):

`.map()` is a cool method, but keep in mind it's not compatible with legacy IE (<9). If you want something that'll work everywhere, go for this:

```
var arrayOfObjects = [ 
    {name: "a", happyName: "bob" },
    {name: "b", happyName: "cow" },
    {name: "c", happyName: "moo" },
    {name: "d", happyName: "jen" }
],
array = [],
i = 0,
len = arrayOfObjects.length;

for(;i<len;i++) {
    array.push(arrayOfObjects[i].name);
}

// output => [ "a","b","c","d"]
```